# Spring State Machine with nested state machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I want to run a state machine with different configuration inside of my 'primary' state machine.
I haven't found something relevant in the web and i do not have a lot experience in Spring State Machine.

One solution i have found is to send an event to the second state machine when the primary one finished its flow. However it is not enough satisfied for me.

If someone knows and share how to create a nested state machine it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, your flow looks like below:

```
                          US flow [stock -> deliver]
created -> processing ->                                             -> completed
                          Canada flow [stock -> export -> deliver]
```

If it is true, you can use [Hierarchical States](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#configuring-hierarchical-states) and [Regions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#configuring-regions) to configure nested states. You can configure your flow with hierarchical states and mark each nested flow as a region. See examples [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-examples-showcase)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have 2 state machines with 2 different configuration that work independently. Now a need appears to run a flow similar with the 2nd state machine inside the first one. Therefore i want to connect them to run as one or like one

Comment: Is it acceptable in your case to duplicate second state machine configuration to `primary` one as nested states?

Comment: It seems that i cannot since the two configurations use different States and Events. After all my search i think i cannot to connect the 2 SMs as i described.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion the way you want to design your state machine is not practical, you either have to define two different states, PROCESSING_US and PROCESSING_CANADA, decide via a Guard condition which State you would go and make the correct process chain, or use another unspoken concept that I discuss here [Master / Slave State Machines](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/extremely-ajaxified-web-application-with-spring-webflow-primefaces-and-state-machines/#master_slave). In your place I would have 2 Slave State Machines that can only exist in the context of you Master State Machine (which you called Primary).

When you arrive to PROCESSING State, you decide it is US or Canada Processing and delegate to UsProcessingSlaveStateMachine or CanadaProcessingSlaveStateMachine, this way you would have a clean design.

I have another [blog](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/model-driven-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/#uml_model_master) that discuss Master / Slave State Machine concept but it relies another technology stack, Akka Finite State Machine, but it might help understand the concepts better.